# ANOVA 1-way - How to calculate SSF

Tags: regression, anova

I'm studying and I can't find an answer to make the ANOVA table for this.
I have 4 groups, with mean and variance group. My N=60, n=15 for each group.

To find Sum Square Errors I did Sum( ni * variance i) but I don't know how to calculate SST or SSF having just this information.

I could have made SST = total variance * N

And then SSF=SST-SSE, but I don't know how to get to total variance from this information.

Thank you

Comment: Apparently OP is interested only in Excel implementation of the key formulas. For me personally, that is off-topic.

Comment: Hey Bruce thanks for your time once again! I was able to solve it after more research. As for the Excel it was because I only had my exercises solved in Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your balanced design (15 replicates in each of four groups), a quick answer can be illustrated using fictitious data sampled in R:

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = round(rnorm(15, 50, 7),2)
x2 = round(rnorm(15, 51, 7),2)
x3 = round(rnorm(15, 51, 7),2)
x4 = round(rnorm(15, 52, 7),2)
x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4)
g = as.factor(rep(1:4, each=15))
```

In R, there are several ways to get relevant parts of the ANOVA
table. One is as follows, giving Total Sum of Squares =  $3485.53.$

```
aov(x~g)
Call:
   aov(formula = x ~ g)

Terms:
                       g Residuals
Sum of Squares   113.405  3372.125
Deg. of Freedom        3        56

Residual standard error: 7.75993
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

The total sum of squares is $113.405 + 3372.125 =  3485.53.$

Another method gives the same answer:

```
anova(lm(x ~ g))

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
g          3  113.4  37.802  0.6278 0.6001
Residuals 56 3372.1  60.217
```

Also, 'mean squared' entries are 'sum of squared entries' divided by 'degrees of freedom' and 'mean squared entries' can be found from group means and variances. Thus,
$\mathrm{MSE = MS(Resid)} = 60.217$ and
$\mathrm{MSF = MS(Group)} = 37.80$ agree
with the outputs above.

```
MSE = mean(c(var(x1),var(x2),var(x3),var(x4)));  MSE
[1] 60.21651
MSF = 15*var(c(mean(x1),mean(x2),mean(x3),mean(x4)));  MSF
[1] 37.80172
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your time answering with so much detail. However I need to know the formulas to calculate SSE, SST and SSF in excel. I only have averages and variance for each group. mean<-(24.5, 25.8, 28.1, 29.5) variance<-(4.38, 3.49, 3.58, 3.58) and n<-(15, 15, 15, 15) N=60. I have from my notes the if I sumprod(variance*n) <- 4.38*15+3.49*15+3.58*15+3.58*15) I get SSE. However I have seen different answers for this and I don't know how to calculate either SST or SSF

Comment: Formulas in mathematical notation are widely available in intermediate-level applied statistics texts and online. Also, for the balanced one-way ANOVA, they are implemented in my R code. I don't use Excel. Maybe someone else is interested in illustrating that.